# Slider's size changes when initialised

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

First of all, thanks for taking the time to read!

So, what I've encountered is the following;
I made a simple thingy before my exam tomorrow. I was trying to change the background of a canvas when I changed the value of the slider above. 
After having errors thown to my face over and over, I gave in and opened debug.
Aaand apparently the method that has to fire up when something changes, fires up when the Mainwindow.xaml initialises the components. (And the canvas' background is pitchblack no matter what value the slider has. So I guess the parse from string to byte doesn't work either) 
Do I have to use another event?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HSlider_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        doShit(HSlider.Value);//when debugging, the program stops here before the window even pops up
    }

    private void VSlider_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        doShit(VSlider.Value);
    }

    private void doShit(double Value)
    {
        SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush();
        for (int count = 0; count < Value; ++count)
        {
            br.Color = Color.FromRgb(Byte.Parse(Value.ToString()), Byte.Parse(Value.ToString()), Byte.Parse(Value.ToString()));
        }
        drawingCanvas.Background = (br);
    }
```

Comment: What were the errors you received?

Comment: incrementing the sliders will change your color value by 1, not much a change (EG Color(0,0,0) is black Color(1,1,1) is black too. Additionally, the SizeChanged event is called when the slider grows or shrinks, I think you want to look at ValueChanged Event. You could multiply the Value*16 to obtain larger color numbers, but contstraint checks would have to be applied.

Comment: Well, at first I tried to add Rectangles to the canvas to which Visual Studio prompted me that they were already a Child and therefor could not be added (this error persisted even after I added an extra line to clear the canvas entirely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim,

to clarify the color thing, try this. Slider Minvalue=0, MaxValue=15. Then your method is much simpler.

```
     private void doShit(double Value)
{
    Value = Math.Min(Value, 15)
    SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush();
    br.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, (int) Value*16, (int) Value*16, (int) Value*16);
    drawingCanvas.Background = (br);
}
```

Comment: This did indeed fix the color issue, did not think about the values going up to 255 :) And for the error part, I figured it out! The required event was not SizeChanged but ValueChanged, which made more sense anyway.